# How do I create a nav bar link menu with a logo and a dropdown list for some of the choices and a search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

How do I make a nav bar similar to the one for tmz.com? It has a logo, some choices, a dropdown list for one of the nav menu items and a search bar. It is centered. I want the menu in the nabber to have a dropdown that lists more menu items users can click on to go to a new page and get more information on that item.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
    background: url(ghettoshop.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #header {width:100%; height:80px; background: black; box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px gray;}

    #navbar {width:1000px; height: 80px;float:right;}

    #navbar> li{
    width:190px;
    list-style: none; 
    float:left;
}

    li>a{
    display: block; 
    color:white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    li>a:hover,
    li>a:focus{
    background: #228B22; color:black;
}

#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
    #logo>img {
    width: 410px;
    height: 80px;
}

    li>a:hover,
    li>a:focus{
    background: #228B22; color:black;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="shop2.html">
    <img src="logo6.jpeg" alt="logo" /></a></div>
    <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="shop2.html"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>

                
                <li><a href="#"> Merchandise </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Delivery </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you can get started with something like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/). If you do not want to use a css framework, you might want to use flexbox to center your menu items vertically next to each other

Comment: the best and easiest way for you to do this would be bootstrap instead of doing this on your own
as mentioned bootstrap works really great in this situation

Comment: Hi boredaf, welcome to SO. On SO you are expected to post a [reprex], it is not a software development site. Search online for 'css navbar horizontal' and you will find many examples.

Comment: None of these responses were helpful. Searching through examples of what I do not want is not that helpful. I want a specific look. Currently, I do not see an option to do exactly what I want with bootstrap. If that is a solution, can someone provide a link for that code?

Comment: I do not want a logo with a nav bar below it or a vertically aligned navbar. I want the navbar to be horizontally aligned with the logo to the left, links to the right. I want some but not all of the links to have dropdown menu options. Any help is appreciated. I already have what I want so far except for the dropdown menus.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropdown{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%; 
    height:80px; 
    background: black; 
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px gray;
}
.logo{
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    float:left;

}
</style>
</head>

<body> 
<div class="dropdown">
            <nav>
                <a href="shop2.html">
                    
                <img class="logo" src="logo6.jpeg" alt="logo" /></a>
                
                <ul>
                <li><a href="shop2.html"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#"> Merchandise </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Delivery </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```